# Why `type T1 = undefined & {}` is never in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

I looked it up in the TypeScript document.

The docs says NonNullable excludes null or undefined

`type NonNullable<T> = T & {};`

Why `undefined & {}` is `never`?

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#nonnullabletype

Comment: Well if you exclude undefined from undefined... what do you get?

Comment: The parts of this question don't seem directly related to each other.  Presumably you are trying to ask "why is `NonNullable<undefined>` equal to `never`, but you're not actually saying that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have two types, `A`, and `B`, then the [intersection type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) `A & B` corresponds to all values which are *both* `A` *and* `B` at the same time.

The [empty object type `{}`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes-oop.html#empty-types) corresponds to any *object-like* value that you can index into without getting a runtime error.  So all object types are assignable to `{}`, as well as most primitive types like `string` (since `string`s have apparent properties like `toUpperCase`).  The only values which are not assignable to `{}` are `null` and `undefined`.  So you can think of `{}` as being "anything except `null` or `undefined`".

So, the type `undefined & {}` conceptually corresponds to all values which are both `undefined` and "anything *except* `null` or `undefined`".  But there are no values that fit that, so, at least conceptually, `undefined & {}` is the empty intersection and should be equivalent to [the impossible `never` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-never-type) with no values.

In practice, sometimes TypeScript will not immediately reduce empty intersections to `never`.  But any empty intersection involving at least one primitive type like `undefined` will indeed be so reduced, as implemented in [microsoft/TypeScript#31838](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/31838).  So `undefined & {}` is `never`.

---

Note that [the `NonNullable<T>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#nonnullabletype) has [as of TypeScript 4.8](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-8.html#improved-intersection-reduction-union-compatibility-and-narrowing) been redefined to be `T & {}`.  Because `{}` is "everything except `null` or `undefined`", then conceptually an intersection of `T` with `{}` will produce a type like `T` with `null` and `undefined` removed from it.

From that point of view, `NonNullable<undefined>` or `NonNullable<null>` should be `never`, since you're removing something from itself and are left with nothing.

Answer (score 3):

`{}` is a weird type in Typescript, which is why [most style guides](https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/ban-types/) recommend against using it in your own code. Generally speaking, structural types enclosed in curly braces in Typescript are constraints placed upon non-null values. So `{ a: number }` is the type of "anything in Typescript which is non-null-ish and has an `a` field of type `number`".

As a natural extension of this rule, `{}` is the type with no constraints, except for the non-null part. So `{}` is the type of all non-null-ish values in Typescript. It includes things like `{}` (obviously), other objects like `{ a: 1 }` and `{ b: "Some string" }`, but it also includes numbers and strings. The number `42` is a non-null-ish value which satisfies all of the (zero) properties we placed upon our type, so `42` is of type `{}`.

However, `{}` is still defined not to accept `null` or `undefined`, so `{} & undefined` must contain no values.

Note that this is all only true in `--strictNullChecks`. WIthout `--strictNullChecks`, `null` and `undefined` inhabit every type in Typescript, and `{} & undefined` is equivalent to simply `undefined`, a type which contains the two values `undefined` and `null`.